# Powershell to create list of duplicated proxyaddresses as .CSV file?

Tags: powershell

I need some way to report which users in our AD are having duplicated ProxyAddresses or aliases.

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties proxyaddresses |
Select-Object Name,
              @{ L = "proxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like 'smtp:*') -join ";" } } |
              export-csv -Path C:\proxyaddresses.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I need only the duplicated AD user, not the whole lot, how can I get that report to . CSV file?

Comment: A bit unclear.. Do you want just the names of users that have duplicates in the ProxyAddresses attribute, or the names **plus** duplicate addresses?

Comment: Hi @Theo, the names Plus the duplicated addresses when possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait before concatening your proxy addresses until you are done working with them.

You can get the duplicates by comparing the count of proxy addresses with the count of unique proxy addresses (`Select-Object -Unique`). If the count mismatch, then you have some dupe in there. If it is the same, then no duplicates.

Here is an example:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -properties proxyaddresses |
    Select-Object Name,
    @{ L = "proxyAddresses"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -like 'smtp:*' } } 
    
$Dupes = $Users | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.proxyaddresses.Count -ne ($_.ProxyAddresses | Select-Object -Unique).Count }
$Dupes | Select Name, @{'Name' = 'ProxyAddresses' ; 'Expression' = { $_.proxyAddresses -join ';' } }  |  export-csv -Path C:\proxyaddresses.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Reference dataset used**

```
$Users = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Value'; proxyaddresses = @('SMTP:a@a.com', 'SMTP:a@a.com' ) }
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Bob Value'; proxyaddresses = @('SMTP:a@a.com', 'b@a.com') }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want:

- Users that have a duplicated address in their proxy list (see answer [@SagePourpre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934946/sage-pourpre)), or
- All users that have the same proxy addresses in their list as another user (this answer)

Create an index (hashtable) where each proxy address refers to a list of users that own that specific proxy address:

```
$ADUserByProxy = @{}
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties proxyaddresses |
ForEach-Object {
    ForEach ($Proxy in $_.ProxyAddresses) {
        if (!$ADUserByProxy.Contains($Proxy)) {
            $ADUserByProxy[$Proxy] = [Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()
        }
        $ADUserByProxy[$Proxy].Add($_)
    }
}
```

Than list all the values that contain more then 1 user:

```
$ADUserByProxy.GetEnumerator() |
Where-Object { $_.Value.Count -gt 1 } |
ForEach-Object { $_.Value } |
Export-csv -Path C:\proxyaddresses.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Great point. I assumed the former without thinking further :)

Comment: @SagePourpre, I guess my answer is actually based on the wrong assumption. but I decided to keep it as is might function as a general answer/approach to find users (or computers) with corresponding items in a multivalue attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the fastest method, but here's an alternative:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses | Foreach-Object { 
    $unique = $_.ProxyAddresses | Select-Object -Unique
    $dupes  = Compare-object -ReferenceObject $unique -DifferenceObject $_.ProxyAddresses -PassThru
    if (@($dupes).Count) {
        $_ | Select-Object Name, @{Name = 'DuplicateAddresses'; Expression = {$dupes -join ';'}}
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\proxyaddresses.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```